# How to make a DEM in QGIS using spot heights and contors

Tags: qgis

I have 2 shapefiles. One is the contors of an area and the other the spot heights. Both of them has a altitude attribute. In ArcGIS there is a tool called topo to raster were you can use both these features to create a dem. In qgis I have only found tools were you can only use one.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is only the interpolation tool that I know of which will create a DEM. Depending on the resolution you're after, you could BUFFER the spot heights, then MERGE SHAPE FILES and run the interpolation tool on that.

Using the graphical modeler would prevent the buffer layer being created making the process a little tidier (and i'm sure there's a better way using the python console). Hope this helps.